# How to get &nbsp to behave properly using HTML Purifier?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, htmlpurifier

I am using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) in my PHP project and am having trouble getting it to work properly with user input.

I am having users enter in HTML using a WYSIWYG editor ([TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)), but whenever a user enters in the HTML entity `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) it gets saved into the database as this weird foreign character (`Â`).

However, the thing is, when I edit the saved entry using the WYSIWYG editor it gets displayed properly as `&nbsp;`. It also functions properly when displayed, only that in the source code it appears as a real space, but not the non-breaking space character.

Also, in the MySQL database it displays as the weird foreign character.

I read the doc about [Unicode and HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) and changed my database and web page encoding to be UTF-8, but I am still having problems with the non-breaking space character not being mangled. The other HTML entities, such as `&lt;` and `&gt;`, get saved as `<` and `>`, but why not `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Wrap entities and HTML in code tags (look at my edit!) to prevent them from being interpreted as actual HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-breaking space isn't being saved in your database as one weird foreign character, it's being saved as *two* characters. The Unicode non-breaking space character is encoded in UTF-8 as `0xC2 0xA0`, which in ISO-8859-1 looks like "Â " (i.e. a weird foreign character followed by a non-breaking space).

You're probably forgetting to do `SET NAMES 'utf8'` on your database connection, which causes PHP to send its data to MySQL as ISO-8859-1 (the default).

Have a look at "[UTF-8 all the way through…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)" to see how to properly set up UTF-8 when using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It may also help you to know that `&#160;` is an alternate for `&nbsp;` which you will likely require if you ever output any human readable XML ;)